# Boolean subset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset a data frame with pandas in python.

Currently I am using

```
df_update = df[(df.X == 1) & ((df.Y == 'A') | (df.Y == 'B') | (df.Y == 'C'))]
```

Is there a way to reduce the code to something like:

```
df_update = df[(df.X == 1) & (df.Y in ['A', 'B', 'C'])]
```

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `isin`, or the new [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) syntax:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"X": [1,1,2,1,1], "Y": ["A","D","B","C", "D"]})
>>> df[(df.X == 1) & df.Y.isin(["A","B","C"])]
   X  Y
0  1  A
3  1  C
>>> df.query("X == 1 and Y in ['A','B','C']")
   X  Y
0  1  A
3  1  C
```

`isin` is likely to be faster, especially for small frames; `query` can sometimes be more convenient (and can sometimes be faster for really large frames.)

Comment: just want to chime in to mention that `df.query("x in {}".format(my_list))` has worked for me in the past (in the case when retyping the valid values is too cumbersome)

Comment: @PaulH: for that, you can use `df.query("Y in @my_list")` instead of building a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
df_update = df[(df.X == 1) & df.Y.isin(['A', 'B', 'C'])]
```